# How refresh data in app after update some data?

Tags: swift, swift2

I have a problem with update contact data. View no.1 main view with tableView i have list of contacts. After tap some person from list i have next tableView (view no.2 [push from view 1 to view 2]) with details and button with EDIT. Next if i press Edit i have modal view no3 with edit input when i can change NAME. After SAVE how can i refresh

1. title in tableView navBar
2. title in backButton
3. main tableView in view1

i am using in my view no1

```
let managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext
    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.configureView()
        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: CLInstance.allContactsFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        fetchedResultsController?.delegate = self
        do { try fetchedResultsController?.performFetch() } catch _ {}
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

 func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }



    func controller(
        controller: NSFetchedResultsController,
        didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject,
        atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?,
        forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType,
        newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

            switch type {
            case .Insert:
                tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(NSArray(object: newIndexPath!) as! [NSIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
                break
            case .Delete:
                tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(NSArray(object: indexPath!) as! [NSIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
                break
            case .Move:
                print("move")
                //tableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!, toIndexPath: newIndexPath!)
                break
            case .Update:
                print("update")
                tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)
                break
            }
    }
```

I expected when i save data in this code `NSFetchedResultsController` make update but on my log file i see print out "MOVE" not "UPDATE"how it is possible to do this in some other way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to configure Outlets to any of the on screen elements you want to update. Then you just set their .text attribute to the new value.

The tableView is a bit different though, you have to reload it : myTableView.reloadData()

Just a few gotcha's:

1. If your 'myTableView isn't reloading, make sure that the

   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

function where the tableViewCell is created is using the updated source for creating the cell.

2. Do all your updates on the main thread (if you're using threads)

Comment: Thank You, i added table reload to `viewDidAppear` and now is ok. but i don't know how to create Outlet on backbitten

Comment: backbitten ? Creating an outlet is easy. The easiest way is to make sure you're in the Assistant Editor (showing two panes in the editor). In the left pane you select the Storyboard View, in the right the code for your ViewController. Then for each of the UI Elements (eg. Label) that you want an Outlet for you control drag it from the left pane (storyboard) to the right pane (code). A popup dialog will appear where you can enter your data